# failed to allocate memory while downloading large files in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hii all,
         I am trying to downaload large file in rails using send_data function ,but
    getting error :failes to allocate memory and when trying to download in chunks ,getting only chunk size file only ,below is my code ..

```
File.open(@containerformat.location,"rb"){|f| @data = f.read(8888)}
ext = File.extname(@containerformat.streamName)

if ext == '' 
  extension = File.extname(@containerformat.location)
  send_data(@data,:filename => @containerformat.name+extension,
  :disposition => 'attachment')
else   
  send_data(@data,:filename => @containerformat.streamName,
  :disposition => 'attachment')
end
```

i think  am not able to make loop work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading whole file into memory!
Use `send_file` which uses memory friendly buffered stream.

I would also suggest to use :x_sendfile here, then file may be served directly by front server (Apache, nginx, lighttpd) if proper module is available and configured. This gives very efficient downloads and prevents blocking rails instance by slow clients.

Read about "X-Sendfile" header. http://tn123.ath.cx/mod_xsendfile/

Comment: and how do i send data in chunks using send_data function ??

Comment: send_data and send_file send bytes to stream instantly so you cant invoke them twice in action, please attach you code with send_file - it already does what you try to achieve with "chunked send_data"

Comment: means with above code i can'nt achieve chunked data download ,then how do i download large files and to use send_data or send_file is must foe me

Comment: and could you please tell how do use send_file to downlaod files with above code i just change send_file instead of send_data in above code

Comment: send_file @containerformat.location, :filename => "filename-here.ext" #location should be absolute

Comment: yaa did it and but when i try to download 284 mb of file my server

Comment: for small file its(send_file) working fine but for large what should i do gertas

Comment: It seems its mongrel issue here, try patch with http://code.google.com/p/ruby-mongrel-x-sendfile/ or try another ruby server or use front server with X-Sendfile . Generally X-Sendfile is recommended for production. For development and test environment plain send_file should be sufficient.

Comment: but i am new to rails how do i configure apache as front server means how to i use X-Sendfile and all that ,am running mongel thats it and runing it in development mode

Comment: I suggest you to setup Apache2 with http://tn123.ath.cx/mod_xsendfile/ and Passenger http://www.modrails.com/ as mongrel replacement for production - much easier. Google for tutorials and howtos for your production OS.