# Current way to download large files in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I used to use the method outlined by Obie Fernandez to download files:

http://www.therailsway.com/2009/2/22/file-downloads-done-right/

But this way is a bit outdated so curious what is better?  My fear is if you have multiple clients downloading large files too much memory would be eaten up.

I need to camo the S3 url and control who can download what.  Perhaps this method is still fine or maybe streaming is the way to go.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you thought about delayed_job?

Comment: So place the download into a delayed_job so it runs asynchronously?  Wouldn't that still be doing the same tech but simply in the background?  Right now I download, read the file into memory, then send it to the user.  I do this so I can control access to files and also camo the S3 url.

Comment: Hmm - may have answered my question - looks like send_file streams the file vs. loading it all into memory.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724073/failed-to-allocate-memory-while-downloading-large-files-in-rails

Comment: Looks like send_file needs the file vs. url to it.  SO you would still be required to download it to the app before sending to the user.

Comment: Your link appears to be broken as of 5/2/17